# Hairpins crescendo text symbol in Musixtex

Tags: musixtex

To display the crescendo hairpins symbol in text document, it is required to use the Musixtex package as follow:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
    \setlines{1}{0}
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \startpiece%
    \Notes\icresc\en%
    \allbarrules\hidebarrule
    \Notes\loff\tcresc\en%
    \endpiece
  \end{music}

\end{document}
```

The current output is as follow:
[image: current output]

The expected output (note that the final bar should be deleted):
[image: expected output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command \sepbarrules was needed, now it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas
\input {musixbm} % compatibilidad garrapateas con ganchos o con barras
\input {musixbbm} % compatibilidad semi garrapateas con ganchos o con barras

\newlength{\musicwidth}%new
\setlength{\musicwidth}{0.75\textwidth}%new, can be set for each instance of a figure environment 

\begin{document}

\begin{music}
    \instrumentnumber{1}
    \setclefsymbol{1}{\empty}%
    \nostartrule
    \setlines{1}{0}
    \hsize=\musicwidth
    \nobarnumbers
    \sepbarrules%---New added
    \startpiece%
    \Notes\icresc\en%
    \allbarrules\hidebarrule
    \Notes\loff\tcresc\en%
    \endpiece
  \end{music}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: solved]